# How to update custom ROM with CWM

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

How to update custom ROM with Clockwork Mod. Currently I have [amzen 5 kitkat](http://serbadroid.blogspot.com/2014/11/rom-amzen-5-kitkat-for-mt6572.html) and want to update to version 6. I know how to flash ROM but I don't know how to update it. Does **install .zip from sdcard** overwrite earlier ROM or will make bootloop. Other option is to update in settings 'system's updates' but I don't have Internet connection and also this custom ROM probably doesn't support reverse tethering (Internet USB)

Comment: Assuming you are on a previous version of the same ROM, the recovery shouldn't matter, just flash the new ROM ZIP (and Gapps if not included in the ROM) and wipe caches... Do not wipe data, and reboot. That is normally all you need to do. Whenever upgrading, make sure to do a backup of your data first, because issues do occur sometimes and one of the first troubleshooting steps with issues on custom ROMs is to clean flash.

Comment: @acejavelin Must I port update before updating from earlier also ported rom or only download .zip file with update and flash rom?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand... What do you mean port ROM? It's either for your device or not.

Comment: ok understand this